# preg_match URL with possible question mark

Tags: php, regex

So I have a string (that is dynamic). It is $url.. now the URL string can sometimes look like this:
http://site.com/blah123

or

http://site.com/blah123?blahblah

right now I have it doing

```
    preg_match("/site.com\/(.*)/",$info[url],$matches);
    $gethash = $matches[1];
```

but it gets thrown off when there is a ? mark statement afterwords.

How can I have it grab justeverything between the slash (/) and the question mark, when there IS a question mark, but when there ISN'T a question mark, just grab everything after the slash (/)

Answer (score 3):

Just exclude `?`:

```
preg_match('/site\.com\/([^?]*)/', $info[url], $matches);
```

Comment: Just for reference, this works because the regex engine attempts to grab as many characters as possible (it is greedy). The "." character matches any character, so the regex engine continues to the end of the string. By telling it not to match the question mark, it matches up until it can't match any more, and stops just before including the question mark in the matched text.

Comment: I think you may need to escape the question mark, because it is special in regular expressions, so you would do: '/site\\.com\\/([^\\?]*)/'

Comment: @Alex: The question mark does not need escaping, but the period does, yes.

Comment: @Alex: The question mark doesn't need escaping and the backslashes don't need double-escaping, but yes, you're right, the period does. My mistake.

Comment: @JoshDaniels: It works for me, maybe you could give me something a little better than "that did not work at all"? http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZTVmIc